# I can't access a related field from a template in Django, but it works in the shell, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

EDIT: Added model classes at the bottom.

I have this view code that takes input from a Django form and uses it to search the database for values.

```
class SearchResults(generic.FormView):
    template_name = 'search_results.html'
    context_object_name = 'submissions'
    form_class = SearchForm
    model = Submissions

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SearchResults, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        level = self.request.GET['level']
        media_type = self.request.GET['media_type']
        tags = MajorTags.objects.filter(
            tag__icontains=self.request.GET['search'])
        tag_ids = [t.id for t in tags]
        context['results'] = Submissions.objects.filter(
            tags__id__in=tag_ids,
            level__contains=level,
            media_type__contains=media_type)
        return context
```

That then ends up being rendered by this template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get" class="global-search">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}.
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
<ul>
    {% for resource in results %}
    <li> <a href="/resources{%url 'resource' resource.id%}"> {{resource.url}} </a> {{resource.stats_set}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}

</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem is that `{{resource.stats_set}}` returns nothing in the template. (The exact output is `doc_sub.Stats.None`.) However, when I run the following code in the shell, I get the result I'm looking for.

```
from doc_sub.models import MajorTags, Submissions
tags = MajorTags.objects.filter(tag__icontains='Theology')
tag_ids = [t.id for t in tags]
level = 'Introductory'
media_type='HTML'
context = Submissions.objects.filter(tags__id__in=tag_ids, level__contains=level,  media_type__contains=media_type)
for i in context:
    print i.stats_set.values()
```

Here are the necessary models:

```
class Submissions(models.Model):
    LEVEL = (
        ('Introductory', 'Introductory'),
        ('Intermediate', 'Intermediate'),
        ('Academic', 'Academic'),
    )

    MEDIA_TYPE = (
        ('HTML', 'HTML'),
        ('PDF', 'PDF'),
        ('Video', 'Video'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)
    tags = models.ForeignKey(MajorTags, default=0)
    level = models.CharField(choices=LEVEL, max_length=25)
    media_type = models.CharField(choices=MEDIA_TYPE, max_length=25)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url
class Stats(models.Model):
    url = models.ForeignKey(Submissions)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    avg = models.FloatField(default=0)
    std_dev = models.FloatField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.url.url + " " + str(self.avg)
```

Comment: Well, you're calling `stats_set.values` in the shell, but only `stats_set` in the template. What happens when you add the `.values`?

Comment: can you show us your Sumbissions class please ?

Comment: That worked, but for some reason I can't access the individual elements of that list. I've tried stats_set.avg (the component that I want) and stats_set.values.avg and a couple other variations of that with no luck. Any help there?

Comment: I'll edit the question to include the necessary models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. If I had been smart and RTFM I may have figured it out sooner, however, I was trying to access the value the wrong way. I was doing this: `print t.stats_set.values()[0]['avg']` like I was accessing values in a normal python context, but I needed to be doing this: `resource.stats_set.values.0.avg`